Combinatorial Geometry problem from secondary category of BdMO 2024
This problem is from the secondary category of BdMO (Bangladesh Math Olympiad) 2024.

A set consisting of  points on a plane is called a “ −” if any three of its points are located in vertices of an isosceles triangle. Find all positive integers  for which there exists a set of “ −”.

My first idea was to imagine the perpendicular bisectors of the line segments connecting each point in the plane and see if there's any way to find out if a point lies on that perpendicular bisector or not.

See here.

This question is difficult, and was posed by recognized mathematician Paul Erdos who in 1946 posed is a problem in the American Mathematical Monthly. The solution was given by a PHD student at the University of Missouri.
The solution is complicated in the sense there are lots of cases to consider and spans two pages, it can be read here. After some quick scratch work, you will realize that $n \geq 6$, and intuitively conjecture that $n \leq 6$ (i.e. $6$ is the maximum). Choose "alternate access options" if you're not at a university, it is free.

The wording here is not very clear to me, but let me take a stab at this.
It seems that I can create an arbitrarily large set of points that does not contain an isosceles triangle in it.
Take a half circle running from 0 to pi radians. Then place a point at the point on the arc corresponding to pi radians. Then the next point at pi/2 radians. Then pi/3. Continue in this way as many times as you like.
Are there isosceles triangles here? It seems not! Consider your first chord between pi and pi/2 radians. Any other chord at least as long as this one in our set must include the point at pi radians, so it must be strictly longer.
As for the next chord, between pi/2 and pi/3, are there other chords of the same length? It seems not! We've already done away with any chord that contains the point at pi radians as being too large. So we restrict to just the points between pi/2 radians and fewer. By a similar argument to before, we see that any other chord at least as long as this one must include the point at pi/2 radians, and hence must be strictly larger.
Continuing in this way, we see that this is a set of points (arbitrarily large) that does not contain an isosceles triangle.

Isn't this the exact opposite of what the question asks for?
